# Repetir uma animação CSS toda vez que clico no botão (com Javascript)

Tags: javascript, css, animação

Como faço para repetir uma animação toda vez que clico em algum elemento com javascript, eu tentei fazer, porém só funciona uma vez (no primeiro clique), após clicar, a animação já fica no código HTML (caso eu veja pelo inspecionar elemento), então não adianta eu clicar novamente, pois não funciona.

Estou fazendo desta forma:

```
variavel.onclick = function efeito() {
    this.style.animation = 'nomeAnimacao 1s linear';
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Pode primeiro colocar a animação sem nada com:

```
this.style.animation = '';
```

E depois voltar a aplicar a animação. O pormenor é que tem de dar um pequeno intervalo de tempo para a alteração ser interpretada. Pode fazer isso re-aplicando de novo o valor dentro de um [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout):

```
setTimeout(() => this.style.animation = 'nomeAnimacao 1s linear', 5);
```

Veja o exemplo:

```js
const botaoAnimar = document.getElementById("animar");
const caixa = document.querySelector(".caixa");

botaoAnimar.addEventListener("click", ()=> {
  caixa.style.animation = "";
  setTimeout(() => caixa.style.animation = "deslizar 1s linear", 5);
});
```

```css
.caixa {
  background-color:lightGreen;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}

@keyframes deslizar{
  0%   { margin-left: 0px; }
  50%  { margin-left: 200px; }
  100% { margin-left: 0px; }
}
```

```html
<div class="caixa"></div>
<button id="animar">Animar</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode setar a propriedade do `animation` para `"none"` e usar `setTimeout` que irá esvaziar a propriedade do `animation` para vazio `""` e em seguida ele irá herdar a propriedade do CSS novamente.

**Exemplo:**

```js
variavel = document.getElementById("butt");

variavel.onclick = function efeito() {
   var e = document.getElementById("div");
   e.style.animation = "none";
   setTimeout(function() {
      e.style.animation = "";
   }, 100);
}
```

```css
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    animation: nomeAnimacao 4s linear;
}

@keyframes nomeAnimacao {
    0%   {background-color: red;}
    25%  {background-color: yellow;}
    50%  {background-color: blue;}
    100% {background-color: green;}
}
```

```html
<div id="div"></div>
<br>
<button id="butt" type="button">Reiniciar</button>
```

### Edit

Quando você seta `"none"` em uma animação, ela é automaticamente cancelada, voltando ao seu estado inicial. Ao esvaziar o estilo, ele assume o estilo do CSS e reinicia. Veja na imagem que o estilo aceita `none`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No caso de outros estilos, como `width`, o comportamento é parecido, exceto que o `width` não aceita `none`. Veja um exemplo:

```js
variavel = document.getElementById("dvd");

variavel.onclick = function efeito() {
   var e = document.getElementById("div");
   e.style.width = "100px";
   setTimeout(function() {
      e.style.width = "";
   }, 2000);
}
```

```css
div{
   width: 300px;
   height: 50px;
   background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="div">Clique no botão e aguarde 2s</div>
<input type="button" value="ok" id="dvd">
```

Comment: Então, sempre que eu esvaziar uma propriedade css de algum elemento, ele volta ao padrão que foi definido na folha de estilo?

Comment: Vou até colocar um exemplo na resposta disso com outro estilo